# HTTP error 403 in Python 3 Tumblr Scraping even after User-Agent headers added

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, urllib

I try to crawl the most recent images that contain specific keyword tags from tumblr without logining or using api. However I receive error 403 when I run my code, even though I have added User-Agent data into the headers.
Could anyone help me? Thank you and sorry about my poor English.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re   

url='https://www.tumblr.com/search/flowers/recent'

data={}
data['q']='flowers'
data['sort']='recent'
data['post_view']='masonry'
data['blogs_before']=8
data['num_blogs_shown']=8
data['num_posts_shown']=0
data['before']=0
data['blog_page']=1
data['post_page']=1
data['filter_nsfw']='true'
data['filter_post_type']='photo'
data['next_ad_offset']=0
data['ad_placement_id']=0
data['more_posts']='true'


data=urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')    
req=urllib.request.Request(url,data)

#add headers
req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36')

response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)        
html=response.read().decode('utf8')



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D47\Desktop\tumblr.py", line 29, in <module>
    response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "D:\Temp\python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "D:\Temp\python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 471, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "D:\Temp\python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 581, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "D:\Temp\python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "D:\Temp\python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Temp\python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: It works after adding ['referer'] part into the header

Comment: What exactly did you change? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: head['referer']= URL  #URL is the tumblr url you request

Comment: @D47 could you please explain a bit better what you did? I am having the same problem